# TinyMCE does not display formatted text in editor

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, tinymce

When I create formatted text in tinyMCE and save it to the database it works good, I can see the visible changes I made in the editor, and in the database the code looks great:

```
<p><span style="background-color: #888888; color: #99cc00;">BLAAT</span> Some other tekst</p>
```

But when I load the content from the database back into the editor it looks like plain text:
[image]

I can see no js errors or php errors, and I have no idea what so ever at the moment on where to look for possible mistakes. Any directions?

Comment: If you go to HTML view in tiny MCE, what does it show?  With or without HTML tags?

Comment: Have that function disbaled, but when I look in the code all between the textEditor is 'BLAAT Some other tekst' without any tags. So These are removed in the population of my form...

Comment: I figured it out. With Zend I apply the stripTags filter. Did not know that this works backwards as well: it also strip tags when populating a form field. Thanks for pointing it out, completly did not think of looking there!

Comment: If you found a solution for your error, you should post it as an answer to your own question and accept it so the question does not remain open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before populating the form I disable the stripTags filter. The form populates perfectly. Then before getting the data again and putting it in the database I set the stripTags again. A bit of a work around, but it gets the job done.